# Define Objecttype as Part of an other Class or Interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an Interface `Data` which is structured like this:

```
interface Data {
    message: string;
    Id: string;
    uid: string;
}
```

Data with this Structure uploads to a database.
When I want to Update one Element on my database I call a function `updateData(updatedData)` and I want this variable `updatedData` to be an Object not of type `Data` but all properties should be part of the Datainterface.

I tried to find an answer to this question but I don‘t even know how to express my question in a short way so I can get some good results from a search engine.

So maybe you can give me at least a keyword to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly you just want partial of Data interface? if so, you can use partial type in ts.

```
interface IData {
  message: string;
  id: string;
  uid: string;
}

type partialData = Partial<IData>;

const messageData: partialData = {
  message: 'only message updated',
};

const idData: partialData = {
  id: 'only id updated',
};

const updateData = (data: partialData) => {
  console.log();
};

updateData(messageData);
updateData(idData);
```

from ts definition

```
type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | undefined; }
```

it just make all properties as optional

Comment: Thank you that’s exactly what I was looking for.